# Why are external documents found only under the default language?

Tags: php, typo3

We're using indexed_search as the search solution on one of our websites. Lately I've had an issue with the indexed search and `.pdf` documents on a website I maintain.

Indexed search would index the documents but would only "link" them to the default language. So if you would browse the website with a different language selected, the documents would never turn up in any search results.

Is it possible to resolve this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using indexed search to also index documents on your site (like `.pdf` files), they will only be found when the user has the default language selected. To make indexed search index those files properly under the language of the page where the file was found, you have to adjust `class.indexer.php`.

In the method `submitFilePage()`, find the array `$fields` and add `sys_language_id` to it, like so:

```
$fields = array(
    'phash' => $hash['phash'],
    'phash_grouping' => $hash['phash_grouping'],
    'cHashParams' => serialize($subinfo),
    'contentHash' => $content_md5h,
    'data_filename' => $file,
    'item_type' => $storeItemType,
    'item_title' => trim($contentParts['title']) ? $contentParts['title'] : basename($file),
    'item_description' => $this->bodyDescription($contentParts),
    'item_mtime' => $mtime,
    'item_size' => $size,
    'item_crdate' => $ctime,
    'tstamp' => $GLOBALS['EXEC_TIME'],
    'crdate' => $GLOBALS['EXEC_TIME'],
    'gr_list' => $this->conf['gr_list'],
    'externalUrl' => $fileParts['scheme'] ? 1 : 0,
    'recordUid' => intval($this->conf['recordUid']),
    'freeIndexUid' => intval($this->conf['freeIndexUid']),
    'freeIndexSetId' => intval($this->conf['freeIndexSetId']),
    'sys_language_uid' => $this->conf['sys_language_uid']
);
```

In the method `setExtHashes()`, find the array `$hArray` and add `sys_lang` to it, like so:

```
$hArray = array(
    'file' => $file,
    'sys_lang' => (integer)$this->conf['sys_language_uid']
);
```

### Warning

This method only works if you don't use crawler to invoke indexing of external files. This is controlled by the `useCrawlerForExternalFiles` setting of indexed search.

**Disable this setting!** You should also enable `disableFrontendIndexing` as this could cause very long page load times otherwise (as linked documents on the page might be indexed when a user requests the page).